# JSF Action vs Outcome Attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm new to JSF and am trying to understand what the difference is between the action vs the outcome attributes?  This is not the difference between buttons and command buttons, but between outcome vs action attributes on the **same** button tag.

For instance, I can have:

```
<h:button value="Go" outcome="<value>" />
```

or

```
<h:button value="Go" action="<value>" />
```

I'm not sure when to use which one.  Also, does it make a difference if `<value>` is `<#{bean.methodThatReturnsStringInNavigationRule}>` or `<string literal in navigation rule>`?

Thank you.

Comment: Buttons are typically used for navigation, while command buttons are typically used to perform business actions (and, if necessary, navigation).

Comment: As per your update, no one JSF component has both attributes in the same tag. The `<h:button>` doesn't support `action` attribute at all. The `action` attribute is only supported in `<h:commandButton>`.

Comment: The title of this question makes it much more easy to find now. I don't think it should be considered duplciate anymore.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Difference is that while **action** defines a server method to be executed, **outcome** specifies a view-id which will be destination of your page. You must use JSF inputs depending on the goal you're trying to achieve:

- `<h:button outcome="user-management">` targets you to the user management page. Imagine it as kind of link.
- `<h:commandButton action="#{backingBean.goToUserManagement}"` If you return **"user-management"** in your action method, is doing the same as the **outcome** but it allows you to execute some logic into the server side. It must be embedded into a `h:form` tag.

Also there's no difference between `<h:button outcome="user-management">` or `<h:button outcome="#{backingBean.userManagementNavigationResult}">`, as far as your server side getter method returns "user-management" value.

Comment: `<h:button>` can be used outside of a `<h:form>`, while `<h:commandButton>` can't.

Comment: Also, **action** does not *necessarily* rely on a bean method, but, of course, if it is not the case then why not use `<h:link>`.

Comment: thank you.  and what about the permutation of outcome=#{backing-bean}?

Comment: It just prints the outcome value as string.

Comment: h:button renders as a input type="submit"

Answer (score 4):

If you see JSF 2.0 API there is no `action` attribute for `<h:button>` tag. `<h:button>` is a new tag in JSF 2.0. You can declared the navigation outcome directly in the `outcome` attribute, no need to call a bean to return an outcome like `<h:commandButton>`.

But, if browser’s with JavaScript disabled, the navigation will failed, because the “h:button” tag is generate an “onclick” event to handle the navigation via `window.location.href`.

```
<h:button value="buton" outcome="login" />
```

**//HTML output**

```
<input type="button" 
       onclick="window.location.href='/ContextRoot/faces/login.xhtml; return false;" 
       value="buton" />
```

Source  : [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-button-and-commandbutton-example/). My favorite website where you can find decent examples.

Excellent Blog for JSF  : [BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html). A Hero to so many people on this forum:).