# path in Primefaces

Tags: netbeans, jsf-2, primefaces

```
www.Mysite.com/account/show_account_info.xhtml
www.Mysite.com/civil/steel/lrfd/column/simple_column.xhtml 
www.Mysite.com/index.xhtml
```

Hi
When my current page is index.xhtml with this command button I can go to Page simple_column.xhtml

```
<p:commandButton value="Simple Column" action="civil/steel/lrfd/column/simple_column"/>
```

and My problem is : when my current page is simple_column.xhtml and I want go to show_account_info.xhtm what is my action value?

```
<p:commandButton value="Show Account Info" action="?" />
```

Please Help me.
with a lot of Thanks.
Ali Farzadmehr

Comment: I saw your attempt to ask a question by editing my answer; don't do that. Add a comment to the answer to get clarification. If the component you're working with is the `<p:menutItem/>` you should have that instead in your question instead of the command button you have here. The `action` attribute on the menu item doesn't take a navigation url; use the `url` attribute for that instead

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you're navigating completely out of the current directory, you can use

```
    facesContext.externalContext.applicationContextPath //JSF2.2

    facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath //JSF2.1
```

At the end, you'll have (depending on your version of JSF)

```
    <p:commandButton value="Show Account Info" action="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/account/show_account_info" />
```

---

As a matter of better use of JSF components, you should be using a `<p:button/>` or `<h:button/>`, if all you need to do is navigate. It comes with less overhead and provides support for bookmarkability of your URLs

Related reading:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13070537/1530938)
- [JSF Action vs Outcome Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035232/jsf-action-vs-outcome-attribute)